# NHibernate paginating one to many relation property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having a problem paging over one to many property of a certain class. These are the entities I try to pull from the database and their mapping:

```
class Author
{
     public virtual int id { get; set; }
     public virtual string name { get; set; } 
     public virtual IList<Book> books { get; set; }
}

class Book 
{
     public virtual int id { get; set; }
     public virtual string name { get; set; }
}   

class AuthorMap : ClassMap<Author>
{
     Table('Authors')
     Id(x => x.id)
     Map(x => x.name)
     HasMany(x => x.books)
}

class BookMap : ClassMap<Book>
{
     Table('Books')
     Id(x => x.id)
     Map(x => x.name)
}
```

How do I pull a specific author and query over the books that are connected to the author from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var authorWithBooks = session.Query<Author>().Where(x => x.Name == "...").Fetch(x => x.Books).Single();
```